# Is it possible to have DELETE as an HttpVerb for ASP.NET MVC 3+?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http, backbone.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I know it's possible to have get and post, but I'm using Backbone.js where its methods send with DELETE and PUT also and I don't really want to edit the "framework."

I'm wondering if ASP.net MVC 3 or 4 (or has it been possible since the beginning?) can have Action Methods that receive DELETE or PUT?

*(I know there was a question like this but it was dated 2008 and asp.net mvc 3 or 4 didn't exist yet.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can have `[HttpDelete]` and `[HttpPut]`.

These `ActionMethod` attributes will restrict the request to those `HTTP Verbs`.

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult SomeDeleteAction(){
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, post, put, get, delete are supported. However beware some firewalls block this verb probably because of the lack of prior forms support in the html spec.

A nice article on this is:
http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/01/21/asp-net-mvc-tip-46-ndash-donrsquot-use-delete-links-because.aspx